# What do the 4 blue bars underneath the crosshair mean for Doomfist?

Tags: overwatch

[image]

What do these 4 bars represent for Doomfist, who was just released today on the PTR?

Comment: More importantly, "Why isn't he Terry Crews"

Comment: @n_palum Because Terry Crews wouldn't have been a good fit for this serious character. The only reason people want Crews to do a voice for a character is for his "Old Spice" character archetype... I think we can all agree that one of the leaders of Talon, a villain who thinks the only way to better the human race is through conflict, would not randomly rip his clothes off and starting "POWER" while flexing his muscles int he middle of a gunfight.

Comment: @MageXy *I* think that'd be amusing, never said it fits. I understand *why* it isn't, it's only a joke.

Comment: @MageXy: I disagree with your conclusion. If I want to create world conflict on a global scale, I will _definitely_ hire someone who is eager to fight up close (and tons of machismo definitely helps). Nothing rallies the troops more! This reminds me of [Major Armstrong](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Alex_Louis_Armstrong) from Full Metal Alchemist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simply the ammo counter: each bar represents one shot. Doomfist's main weapon can hold up to 4 shots which recharge one by one over time like Tracer's Blink.

Comment: Just a slight correction, given Jeff's video: It's his primary fire but it's never intended to be used as a main weapon. They just put it there to have something.